# How to access Child Controller Scope in Parent Controller in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, scope

I am learning Angular JS and I have something like this with a parent controller and child controller:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Good {{question}}</p>

    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
        <p>Good {{answer}}!</p>
    </div>

    Bind the Child Controller's scope and show here: {{ answer}}
<div>
```

Here the child controller is using the scope like this:

```
$scope.answer = response.answer;
```

**How do I show the `{{ answer }}` outside the child controller and inside the parent controller?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can also use scope prototypal inheritance.

In AngularJS, a child scope normally prototypically inherits from its parent scope. But the `answer` is a primitive (not object type). So we should put our text data to object, to ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play.
(More info here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Controllers:

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.question = 'question';
  $scope.answer = {};
}
function ChildCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.answer.text = 'demo'; 
}
```

View:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Good {{question}}</p>
  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
    <p>Good {{answer.text}}!</p>
  </div>
  Bind the Child Controller's scope and show here: {{ answer.text}}
<div>
```

Comment: That is so simple and easy! I find this method better than `$emit` and `$on`. Thanks heaps @IvanZh

Answer (score 13):

Use the publish/subscribe pattern:

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.question = 'question'
  $scope.$on('response', function (evnt, data) {
    $scope.answer = data;
  });
}

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.$emit('response', 'demo');
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsbin.com/sorexade/6/edit).

Comment: Thanks Minko. I looked at the demo. Should the `{{ answer}}` in the parent controller should show `demo` if its binded with the a `{{ answer }}` in the child controller?

Comment: Actually there is a mistake. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Just one small question. does the `evnt` in `$scope.$on('response', function (evnt, data)` has to be `event` or it doesnt matter and it can hold any string. (sorry if this sounds silly)

Comment: @Neel, it doesn't matter and you can use any string, sometime we use 'e'